# WPF combobox get text while content is binded in template

Tags: wpf, vb.net, xaml, combobox

Title says a lot but here's what I do:

1. Fill the combobox using a custom List(of object)
2. Group them by the "Category" property in that same object

The combobox fill ok and the group are working 100%. However, I want to get the currently selected value. When not binding the combobox, I can easily go `combobox.Text` but it return me "ApplicationName.Object" instead of the actual value.

I figure it is due to the binding and the property not being detected as a string at some point. Just can't figure where and how. I appreciate code but also why it behave like that. I'm no expert when it come to WPF and binding is still a new thing to me. (couple months now)

Code:

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="SummTool_CompanyDD" LostFocus="UpdateFinalSummary" Height="20" Width="180">
    <ComboBox.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock FontWeight="Bold" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.HeaderTemplate>
        </GroupStyle>
    </ComboBox.GroupStyle>
    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Margin="5,0" Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
</ComboBox>
```

vb.net:

```
    Dim itemsCompany As List(Of ItemCB) = New List(Of ItemCB)
    Dim category As String = ""
    For Each company In CompanyList
        If company.StartsWith("**") Then
            category = company.Substring(2)
        Else
            Dim newItem As ItemCB = New ItemCB()
            newItem.Name = company
            newItem.Category = category
            itemsCompany.Add(newItem)
        End If
    Next

    Dim lcv As ListCollectionView = New ListCollectionView(itemsCompany)
    lcv.GroupDescriptions.Add(New PropertyGroupDescription("Category"))

    SummTool_CompanyDD.ItemsSource = lcv
```

The above is for the initialization of the combobox. `CompanyList` is a simple array of strings. Then when I do  `SummTool_CompanyDD.Text`, I get `ApplicationName.ItemCB`.

Thanks and regards,

Comment: I can accept an answer in C# if that help at all. I know vb.net is used that much so WPF with vb.net is even more rare.